# Let $R$ be a ring. Use basic properties of rings to prove that $R$ has the "FOIL" Property and justify each step.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

So prove $(a+b)(c+d) = ac + ad + bc + bd$ for all $a,b,c,d \in R$

So what I said was

$(a+b)(c+d) = a(c+d)+b(c+d)$ - distributive property

$a(c+d)+b(c+d) = ac + ad + bc + bd$

I feel like it cant be this simple though, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What you did is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is good. Remember to be very aware exactly which properties you use. Where do you use the distributive property from the left and where do you use the distributive property from the right?

Notice also that if you had used the distributives properties the other way around, i.e. started out with

$$(a+b)(c+d) =(a+b)c + (a+b)d = ac+bc+ad+bd,$$

you don't exactly get your result. You need a further step of applying commutativity of $+$.

Comment: Yes I should clarify that, good point. Thanks for answering, it just seemed so simple that I wasn't sure. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Thomas no problem. :) I know the feeling.